# Javascript prevent question mark input

Tags: javascript

I have a input box where I am allowing users to use alphabets, arrow, home, del etc keys. I want to prevent users to enter "?" question mark.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', "#element", function(e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
     if (!e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
     // Alphabets
        key >= 65 && key <= 120 ||
     // Backspace and Tab and Enter
        key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
     // Home and End
        key == 35 || key == 36 ||
     // left and right arrows
        key == 37 || key == 39 || key == 50 || key == 191 ||
     // Del and Ins
        key == 46 || key == 45)
         return true;
     return false;
});
```

I know that "/" key code is 191. I am unable to prevent the question mark input. How can I do that? Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the key code is `191`, you just need to check if the shift key was being pressed at the same time.

```
if (e.shiftKey && key === 191)
```

So, in your code, you can just add `(e.shiftKey && key === 191)`.